# Dockerized Redmine, not responding API Rest requests

Tags: docker, rest, docker-compose, postman, redmine

**The problem: (summarized)**
I have a Redmine running on a docker container that lives in a VM ( Centos 8, but I also tried on Ubuntu 18 server and I get the same result). When I make a request through the API Rest, I receive a "timed out" error or similar.

**More Info:**

- I made a program that makes a lot of requests to a Redmine through its API Rest service. The same program was tested on Redmine that is installed locally in a VM, and everything worked perfectly. Which led me to think my program is not the problem.
- When I write, for example, http://ip_of_my_dockerized_redmine:port/users.json ( which returns a list of users according to [the Redmine api rest documentation](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Users)), directly on the browser, it work just fine, and prints the json on the browser.
- Of course, I already activated the REST web service through the web ui.

My program is written in python, so that's why I'm using the python *request* library to make the petitions to the server. However, I also used Postman and the result was the same. Here are some of the errors I'm receiving.

**My docker compose file:**

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:13'
    container_name: 'contenedor_postgres'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<some password>'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=redmine'

  redmine:
    image: 'redmine:4.2.1'
    container_name: 'contenedor_redmine'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - redmine-data:/usr/src/redmine/files
      - redmine-plugins:/usr/src/redmine/plugins
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - 'REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES=postgres'
      - 'REDMINE_DB_DATABASE=redmine'
      - 'REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD=<a password>'

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  redmine-data:
  redmine-plugins:
```

This is a Python request made from a jupyter Notebook, ( Already tested on the Redmine that runs local and worked)

```
# The credentials and other auth. data are stored here
from app import connection
# The request library
import requests
url = "http://ip:3000"
# The request in question.
response = requests.get( url + "/user.json", verify=False, auth=( connection.REDMINE_USER, connection.REDMINE_PASSWORD), timeout=20)
response
```

You can see that I already introduced the `timeout=20` parameter, as it was mention in other similar posts it could work, it didn't.

The response was:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    168         try:
--> 169             conn = connection.create_connection(
    170                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     95     if err is not None:
---> 96         raise err
     97 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     85                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 86             sock.connect(sa)
     87             return sock

timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectTimeoutError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    698             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 699             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    700                 conn,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    393             else:
--> 394                 conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    395 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers)
    233             headers["User-Agent"] = _get_default_user_agent()
--> 234         super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
    235 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1254         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1255         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1256 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1300             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1301         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1302 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1249             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1250         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1251 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1009         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1010         self.send(msg)
   1011 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    949             if self.auto_open:
--> 950                 self.connect()
    951             else:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    199     def connect(self):
--> 200         conn = self._new_conn()
    201         self._prepare_conn(conn)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    173         except SocketTimeout:
--> 174             raise ConnectTimeoutError(
    175                 self,

ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000B37871A940>, 'Connection to <my_vm_ip> timed out. (connect timeout=20)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    754 
--> 755             retries = retries.increment(
    756                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    572         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 573             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    574 

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='<my_vm_ip>', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: /user.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000B37871A940>, 'Connection to <my_vm_ip> timed out. (connect timeout=20)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectTimeout                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-dc378d70e4d9> in <module>
----> 1 response = requests.get( url + "/user.json", verify=False, auth=( connection.REDMINE_USER, connection.REDMINE_PASSWORD), timeout=20)
      2 
      3 response

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 76     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     77 
     78 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    540         }
    541         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    543 
    544         return resp

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    653 
    654         # Send the request
--> 655         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    656 
    657         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    502                 # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811
    503                 if not isinstance(e.reason, NewConnectionError):
--> 504                     raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
    505 
    506             if isinstance(e.reason, ResponseError):

ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='<my_vm_ip>', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: /user.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000B37871A940>, 'Connection to <my_vm_ip> timed out. (connect timeout=20)'))
```

Trying to make the same request with Postman gives the same result:

```
GET http://<my_vm_ip>:3000/users.json
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT <my_vm_ip>:3000
Request Headers
Authorization: Basic YW***************mQ=
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.1
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: b52f****************3de0fbe
Host: <my_vm_ip>:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

I have the feeling, that it might be a problem related to Docker, but i don't know.  I'm not an expert on Docker tbh.

**Edit#1:**
Just for the purposes of an update, I tried to make the ports accesible to the firewall ( In this case firewalld since is Redhat), so:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=3000/tcp
```

and

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5432/tcp
```

returns `succeed` but the result is the same. Not working.

**Edit#2:**
I also tried using the library [*python-redmine*](https://python-redmine.com/index.html), but the result is similar.

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]
```

Comment: Have you checked redmine logs (`docker logs contenedor_redmine`)? Can you see requests that end up with a timeout in logs?

Comment: I did and the funny thing is that I don't receive any registry of my petition. The only way I do is when I make the request explicitly on the web browser, then the last log is http://ip_vm:3000/my/page -> /
ip_requesting - - [10/Jun/2021:05:35:34 UTC] "GET /users.json HTTP/1.1" 200 329
- -> /users.json

Which is what should look the other way too.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my question but it is not mentioned: Can you access your Redmine instance through http and have you enabled the [Rest API](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/rest_api#Authentication) from there?

Eliminating that I would look in the VM firewall settings to see if 3000 can be accessed.

For a quick test you can set docker to expose your redmine's 3000 port through port 80:

```yaml
redmine:
    image: 'redmine:4.2.1'
    container_name: 'contenedor_redmine'
    ...
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, I did enable the REST Web service as it is minded in the doc. (Administration -> Settings -> API -> Enable Rest Web service)

And I did change the port 3000 to 80 as you mentioned but I'm not able to even get in Redmine. ("http // ip:80") leads to a "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Comment: My bad. Docker compose ports configuration mapping is HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT. Edited the response to make the port config: 80:3000

Comment: There was no change in the behaviour after this either. Same result. I think is a bit weird though. Also, I believe is not striking the docker container because it doesn't generate a registry on its log.